# Display a progressHud before the network call in swift

Tags: ios, swift

In my code I am executing a network call which takes few seconds to complete. While it is executing I want to display a progresshud in the background. But the problem is the progresshud does not appears before the network call. It appears right after the network call finishes. I can not understand the issue.

My code is below.

```
    func draw() {

        if !self.drawing) {
            
            self.progressHud.show(in: self.view)

            self.drawing = true
            self.drawImage() // this is the function that takes time to execute
        }
        else if (self.isTransformViewEnabled){
            
           self.drawing = false

        }
    }
```

Please help

Comment: Could you include the implementation of `drawImage()`? If the function is synchronous, and `draw()` is called from the main queue (e.g. a button tap), no changes to the UI will be present until the `drawImage()` function has completed. Additionally, please include the code that uses the `drawing` property (e.g. where you display your progress HUD).

Comment: @NicklasJensen yes u were correct ```draw()``` was also called from the main queue. So no changes happened until it finish execution.  Thank u. (If u want add ur comment as an answer i ll accept)

Comment: That's okay. You've gotten 2 fine answers below which is all that matters. Feel free to accept either one of those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are calling the network call synchronously. So it waits the request to complete for showing hud.  You can call in on Main thread on async

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
   //your code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**This is happening because you are making the network call on the main queue synchronously. Hence the UI is updated after the call is completed.**

**Please make the network call asynchronously in a different queue and the HUD will show up on the screen.**

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.drawImage()
}
```

Let me know if it works for you.

Happy to help.

Thanks.